# PHP - How to "add hours" to an integer?

Tags: php, date

I want something that seems simple but can't figure out :

I have an integer which in my program is an hour, in a 24h format (ie '18') and I want to add X (ie '7') hours to it.

How do I add hours to something that is not at date object whatsoever. Something that would work like this :

```
18 + 7 = 1
```

Comment: You could utilize the modulus `%` operator?  `(18 + 7) % 24 == 1`

Comment: do you need to keep track of how many days this result is, or are you purely interested in the resulting hour value?

Comment: @MarcB I'd presume he only cares about hours, because he says it's "not [a] date object whatsoever"

Comment: @Blake: doesn't matter. intervals aren't date objects, but there's going to be someone who needs to know that something took 10 days and 1 hour, v.s. only 1 hour.

Comment: @MarcB I only care about the hour in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the modulus operator is what you're after. See this example:

`echo ((18 + 7) % 24); // Output: 1`

Answer (score 0):

Please use % (modulus) for this.

```
(18 + 7) % 24 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

% operator could come to your rescue:

```
  <?php
    $hour_24_format =18;
    $x_hours = 7;
    define("_TWENTY_FOUR_",24);
     $result = ($hour_24_format + $x_hours)% _TWENTY_FOUR_ ; 
  ?>
```